# How to get selected div width when resize browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to get selected div width according to following algorithm:

1. If user resize browser then get div width according to resize browser div.
2. If user don't resize browser then get div width normally.

Here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($(window).resize) {
        var width = $('#main_header .wrapper').width($(window).resize);
    }
    else {
        var width = $('#main_header .wrapper').width;
    }

});
```

My code don't work, Please, any one can help me solving this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little function will get the width of `#main_header .wrapper` and update it on resize:

```
$(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('#main_header .wrapper');//the element we want to measure
    var wrapperWidth = $wrapper.width();//get its width    
    $wrapper.text(wrapperWidth);//dunno what you want to do with wrapperWidth but here im setting it as the text of .wrapper just so you can see the value changing
    //add resize listener
    $(window).resize(function() {
        wrapperWidth = $wrapper.width();//re-get the width
        $wrapper.text(wrapperWidth);//update the text value
    });
});
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5rZ4A/

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `if` is the problem. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    alert("$('#main_header .wrapper').width());
  })
});
```

`$(window).resize` will *always* return true because `resize` is a jQuery function. This code instead watches `window` for a `resize` event and calls the inner function when it happens.

I didn’t fill in the inner function because I wasn’t clear on what you wanted to happen upon resize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to use if condition to get div width. can you tell me is it possible. Thanks

Comment: What’s the width you want?

Comment: #main_header .wrapper div width

Comment: I updated the answer with a line that will pop up an alert with the width of that element.